# Type checking and the Haskell hint interpreter library

Tags: haskell, types, hint

How can I get this Haskell code to type check?

```
aesonLensInterpreter :: String -> String -> Interpreter (Maybe Value)
aesonLensInterpreter input expr = do
      setImportsQ [("Prelude", Nothing), ("Data.Map", Just "M"), ("Control.Lens", Nothing), ("Data.Aeson.Lens", Nothing), ("Data.Aeson", Nothing)]
      set [languageExtensions := [OverloadedStrings]]

      let interpExpr = "(" ++ (show input) ++ " :: String)" ++ expr
      v <- interpret interpExpr (as :: ???)
      return $ Just (toJSON v)
```

Basically I want the user to input any possible Lens expression and get the result as a `ToJSON` instance. Since Lens expressions can both return Values or plain Haskell types I'm confused.

Comment: Could you add some concrete example input, please? Also, the code formatting is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the immediate question, replace ??? by any type that's an instance of both `Typeable` and `ToJSON`. The code will typecheck if you use `String`, for instance.

Regarding your goal, if the expressions you want to interpret can actually have different types it looks like this approach won't work directly. Since you're interpreting already, I suggest doing the JSON conversion within the interpreter. Something along the lines of prepending `interpExpr` with `toJSON $` and replacing ??? by `Value`.